# get percent of matched string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to get what percentage of regular expression is matching with the provided string, eg. I have regular expression:

```
^[A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{1,3}$
```

which is trying to match string containing one or two characters, four numbers and one to three characters. Now if I apply this regular expression to `aa1234bb` it will match but if use `aa1234` it will not match.

What I want is after applying regular expression to string it should return the percentage to which string is matched with regular expression, e.g for `aa1234` it is matching almost 70 percent to the given regular expression, if we consider max 10 characters will there in any matched string.

Comment: Only way I can think of doing this is by counting groups. Try expanding your regex to `^([a-z])([a-z])?(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)([a-z])([a-z])?([a-z])?$` and count the number of groups. Otherwise, just do string & match length comparisons.

Comment: Python `re` module match objects have a `span()` method that returns the matched span. You could compare it to the total string length.

Comment: What's the percentage for `1234bb`? How about `aabb`? This gets a lot harder if you want something other than strict left-to-right matching.

Comment: @Kevin
it should also give 70 percent

Answer (score 1):

I can't think how this would be possible in a both totally general (ie. accepts any regular expression) and totally within `re`.

A naive but possibly adequate approach would be a binary search. This assumes that your regular expression is always bound to the front of the string. Below is a rough, untested example to show the idea. Obviously for long strings it may perform the regex quite a few times.

```
def percent_match(regex, target):
    left = 0
    right = len(target) - 1
    current = right // 2
    while left < right:
        if regex.match(target[left:right]):
            left = current
        else:
            right = current
        current = (right - left) // 2
    return m / len(target)
```

If on the other hand you only ever have to do this with one regular expression then @ctwheels approach probably makes most sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try:

```
import re
full_pattern = re.compile(r"^([a-z][a-z]?)?(\d\d\d\d)?([a-z][a-z]?[a-z]?)?$")
num_pos_matches = 3 # 9 groups in our reg

list_of_test_cases = ["aa1234bb","aa1234","1234bb","aabb","+pow","aa","1234","b5555bb"]

def get_match_percentage(in_str):
  m = re.match(full_pattern,in_str)
  if m == None:
    return 0
  m_g = m.groups()

  counter = 0
  for x in m_g:
    if x == None:
      counter+=1
  return round((1 - counter/num_pos_matches) * 100,2)

# print some tests
for test_case in list_of_test_cases:
  print(test_case, " matched ",get_match_percentage(test_case), "% of the ",num_pos_matches, " Regex groups")
```

With the output:

```
aa1234bb  matched  100.0 % of the  3  Regex groups
aa1234  matched  66.67 % of the  3  Regex groups
1234bb  matched  66.67 % of the  3  Regex groups
aabb  matched  66.67 % of the  3  Regex groups
+pow  matched  0 % of the  3  Regex groups
....
```

I think there are definitely some failing cases, for example I would expect `"123dfg"` to give `33.33%`, but it yields

```
123dfg  matched  0 % of the  3  Regex groups
```

So you can probably massage it a little to fix these problems. A lot of credit goes to @ctwheels for the groups idea.